# imageButton flashes at the end of the animation

Tags: android, animation, button

I am trying to make a button that moves. Everything is working ok until the animation ends. What happens is that the button disappears and reapers very fast.

Here is my code:

```
resetLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.reset_layout);
    resetButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reset_button);
    resetLayout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent mE) {

            delta = mE.getX();
            if (mE.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) resetButton
                        .getLayoutParams();
                params.setMargins((int) mE.getX() - 130, 0, 0, 0);
                resetButton.setLayoutParams(params);
            }

            if (mE.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                final TranslateAnimation TAnimation=new TranslateAnimation(0, -mE.getX() + 50, 0, 0)   ;     
                TAnimation.setDuration(250);
                //TAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
                resetButton.startAnimation(TAnimation);
                TAnimation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}

                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) resetButton
                                .getLayoutParams();
                        params.setMargins(-80, 0, 0, 0);
                            resetButton.setLayoutParams(params);

                    }
                });

            //  Handler handler = new Handler();
            //  handler.postDelayed(delayRunnable, 2);
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

As you can see at `onAnimationEnd`, I am changing the button parameters. So, it will be exactly were the animation stops. But you can actually see the flashing moment that it happens.

Why is that so and how can I fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this

```
TAnimation.setFillBefore(true);
```

to the animation object.

Answer (score 0):

you can try giving

```
TAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
```

I think that will solve ur problem